# c++ using system command problem

Tags: c++

hi every body i have a strange problem i write a code in c++ complied it successfully and run it successfully. i compiled with following command 
g++ 1.c -o abc
to run program i use ./abc 
now my problem is that i write a another code in c++ like

```
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  ofstream SaveFile("/home/hadoop/project/hadoop-0.20.0/conf/core-site2.xml");
  SaveFile <<"<configuration>";
  SaveFile<<endl;
  SaveFile<<"<property>";
  SaveFile<<endl;
  savefile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

now i want to run abc in this code how to do this ?
how to use or run abc in this file?
how to use ./abc in this program ?

Comment: i accept most of the answers given by you but i dont know how to tell that i accept the answer please expalin me what should i do

Comment: @user513164, acceptance has a specific meaning here - it means clicking on the big open green tick mark to the left of an answer. This will then become a filled-in big green tick mark and "reward" the owner of that answer with 15 points.

Comment: In the answer that you find best solves your problem, click on the check mark on the left side to mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your question title ("... using system ...") says it all. Use:

```
system ("./abc");
```

to run the `./abc` program.

There are *other* ways to run programs from within a program (which usually depend on platform-specific features) but this is the most portable.

---

A full sample program, `testprog.cpp`, to show what I mean:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main (void) {
    std::system ("ls -ald m*");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o testprog testprog.cpp
```

and running the resultant executable `testprog`, this outputs (on my Ubuntu 10.04 box):

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 pax pax 4096 2010-12-14 09:33 myfolder
```

In other words, it runs the `ls -ald m*` command from within the program itself.

Comment: thanks for your answer please explain them i'm using ubuntu 10.04

Comment: @user513164: Have a look at [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and the [`exec` family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/environ.html).

Comment: i used the command but its generate an error  ‘system’ was not declared in this scope tell me what should i do

Comment: @user513164, you need to include `cstdlib` as per the code given. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know about `system()`. If I comment out that line, I similarly get: `testprog.cpp:3: error: ‘system’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: If you use C++ and include `cstdlib` you are only guaranteed to have `system` in `namespace std`, so use `std::system`.